# Ant design table not rendering properly when column extracted in a component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need jsx styled column. I was following example from [docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-jsx)

But I want to extract a separate component as as a table header. After doing that it's not rendering the data as you can see here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jsx-style-api-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-tcykl?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation

> Since this is just a syntax sugar for the prop columns, you can't compose Column and ColumnGroup with other Components.

you can "extract" header like this

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ColumnGroup title="Name">
        <Column title="First Name" dataIndex="firstName" key="firstName" />
        <Column title="Last Name" dataIndex="lastName" key="lastName" />
      </ColumnGroup>
      <Column title="Age" dataIndex="age" key="age" />
      <Column title="Address" dataIndex="address" key="address" />
      <Column
        title="Tags"
        dataIndex="tags"
        key="tags"
        render={(tags) => (
          <>
            {tags.map((tag) => (
              <Tag color="blue" key={tag}>
                {tag}
              </Tag>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      />
      <Column
        title="Action"
        key="action"
        render={(text, record) => (
          <Space size="middle">
            <a>Invite {record.lastName}</a>
            <a>Delete</a>
          </Space>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table dataSource={data}>{Header()}</Table>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

**UPDATE**
Related [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4853)